# Why am i not able to change tooltip background color?

Tags: css, angular5

I am trying to change tooltip background-color. I have try following CSS for it.

```
<i *ngIf="col.field != 'isActive' && col.field != 'action'" class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true" pTooltip="{{col.title}}" tooltipPosition="top" style="font-size:12px;">
</i>
```

**CSS:**

```
.ui-tooltip-text.ui-shadow.ui-corner-all {
    background-color: red;
}
```

But background-color did not change.
Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Have You tried to add /deep/ .ui-tooltip-text ..... ...

Comment: Are you using Angular Material ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried in this way.

:host ::ng-deep .ui-tooltip-text.ui-shadow.ui-corner-all {
    background-color: #1f4567;
}

But it did not any change in tooltip.

Comment: I am using PrimeNG.

Comment: @JayPatel are you write your css in component css file?

Answer (score 0):

> **Option 1**

If you write your **CSS** inside component **CSS** file it'll not apply on your tooltip. Because tooltip is added in body root path so you have to add `ViewEncapsulation` in your component. Please review below code snippet.

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-multi-line-tooltip-so47110595-5blgre)

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class AppComponent  {
}
```

> **Option 2**

Write your css in **Global** css file, which were located in your project **src > assets > css**.

Comment: I have just tried this and it's work. Thanks for it.

Comment: If the answer helps you out, please marks as correct. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have solve this problem by using following css.

`.ui-tooltip .ui-tooltip-text {
  background-color: #1f4567 !important;
}`

But main problem is not about css, When i have tried in Global css file it's work.